# API/CLI to get all the services(ec2, s3, rds..etc) my account is using?

Tags: aws-java-sdk

I tried to look around but couldn't find enough details on how to programatically get list of all services that my aws account is currently using.

Something like: EC2, S3, DynamoDB..etc

Is there a Java API or AWS CLI solution that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no AWS service that exposes that information programatically. However if you're after this information for cost purposes there is the [AWS Budgets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/budgets-managing-costs.html) service that allows you to setup budgets for your AWS resources - it has a public [API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/api-reference.html) which is accessible from Java and the CLI.